# how to decode and save capture image and show in gridview

Tags: android

i want to save captured image in my application memory and view in gridview but when i capture image allication is crash what do i do? how i decode captured image? i want to save captured image in my application memory("data/data/com.myexample/files\CameraRoll\"); what do i do? please help me

```
  Private final int CAMERA_PICTURE=1;
  public final String IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME=System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpeg";  


  File Cameraroll =new file(getFileDir(),"CameraRoll");
  if(CameraRoll.esixts() && CameraRoll.isDirectory())
 {

}
 else 
{
CameraRoll.mkdir
 }

  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File  
  (cameraRoll+"/",IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME))););
      startActivityForResult(intent, Camera_PICTURE);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if (requestCode == Camera_PICTURE) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                       }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File

  (cameraRoll+"/",IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME))););` from your code and you will be able to get the `Bitmap` in `onActivityResult`.

For storing the image you have to do it manually. Either you can save it in `Database` by converting the bitmap to `byte array` and the storing it in `bool` datatype in `Database` or in any file in `sdcard` or `phone's memory`.